# responseJSON in AJAX error response returns undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue where I am trying to retrieve the JSON object of an error response. When I am logged out and try to access the webpage that I am testing, the response in the chrome dev tools returns the correct parameters I had set up for [an error status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7kb1.png).

However, when I make an Ajax call requesting the JSON I get [undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL73Q.png).

I don't want to retrieve the statusText from the Ajax call since it returns "error".

Here is a get request that I am using:

```js
function get(controller, success, error) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseAPI + controller,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: success,
        error: 
            function(err){ 
                var statusCode = err.status;
                if(statusCode >= 400 && statusCode < 500 || statusCode === 0){
                console.log(err.responseJSON)
                }
            },
        beforeSend:
            function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('test' + ":" + 'test1'));
            }
    })
}
```

I am seeing succession with other libraries such as Fetch and Axios. Are there other features that these libraries have over Ajax that prevent me from better error handling?

I'd like to keep my app as lightweight as possible, and I am assuming that Axios and Fetch are wrappers for Ajax with better handling for promises.

https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/203